# Removing trailing white space only for edited lines

Tags: vim, diff, whitespace

I had added the following function in my .vimrc for removing trailing white spaces just before saving

```
fun! <SID>StripTrailingWhitespaces()                                            
    let l = line(".")                                                           
    let c = col(".")                                                            
    %s/\s\+$//e                                                                 
    call cursor(l, c)                                                           
endfun                                                                          

autocmd BufWritePre *.h :call <SID>StripTrailingWhitespaces()
autocmd BufWritePre *.cpp :call <SID>StripTrailingWhitespaces()
autocmd BufWritePre *.c :call <SID>StripTrailingWhitespaces()
```

It works really well. However, in certain cases I would like to remove trailing white spaces only from lines that I have edited. This is to ensure that my `diff` output looks sane as for certain legacy code files almost all lines have trailing back spaces and I do not want to burden my code reviewer with unnecessary diff.

`diff -b` is not a solution right now since it also ignores white spaces from anywhere in a line and sometimes that change is important enough to be include in the `diff` output.

So my question is - is it possible to strip trailing white spaces from only the lines that have been edited in this session in a file in vim?

Comment: I have a highlighting rule that highlights (in a very annoying way) trailing whitespace, so it's very easy for me to see what space should be removed; but +1 because it would be nice to automate most of that.

Comment: Why not, as a one-off task, strip all of the trailing whitespace from all of your legacy files?

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge Doing that obscures who wrote (or last changed) the lines when you run something like git annotate.  (It can still be found, but it takes additional steps.)

Comment: @PaulLynch Yes, it does. But you either care strongly enough about the trailing whitespace to make it worth fixing (in which case it's essentially a bug fix like any other) or you don't. If you felt really strongly about it you could do something clever with `git filter-branch` to rewrite history as if the trailing whitespaces had never been present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[mMontu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8316766/1830736) has the right idea, but it doesn't handle an edge case. Namely, if I move the cursor down, then back up, all in edit mode, it doesn't pick up the changes to those lines.  If we would like to handle this, then we need to store the top and bottom lines visited by the user.  Here is some more robust code, with everything grouped into functions:

```
fun! <SID>SetupTrailingWhitespaces()
    let curline = line('.')
    let b:insert_top = curline
    let b:insert_bottom = curline
endfun

fun! <SID>UpdateTrailingWhitespace()
    let curline = line('.')
    if b:insert_top > curline
        let b:insert_top = curline
    elseif b:insert_bottom < curline
        let b:insert_bottom = curline
    endif
endfun

fun! <SID>StripTrailingWhitespaces()
    let original_cursor = getpos('.')
    exe b:insert_top ',' b:insert_bottom 's/\s\+$//e'
    call setpos('.', original_cursor)
endfun
```

Now we just invoke these functions at the right time:

```
autocmd InsertEnter * :call <SID>SetupTrailingWhitespaces()
autocmd InsertLeave * :call <SID>StripTrailingWhitespaces()
autocmd CursorMovedI * :call <SID>UpdateTrailingWhitespace()
```

Alternatively, I've written [a plugin](https://github.com/thirtythreeforty/lessspace.vim) that provides this updated functionality, with several additional features like stripping in normal mode as well.

Answer (score 4):

One possibility would be to use `autocmd InsertLeave` to strip white spaces from current line every time you leave insert mode:

```
autocmd InsertLeave *.[ch] :call <SID>StripTrailingWhitespaces()
```

, and change substitute command of `StripTrailingWhitespaces()` function changed to

```
s/\s\+$//e
```

It will work if all lines that you include doesn't end in white
spaces, only the last one. It will possible change lines that you didn't
modified, if you enter and exit insert mode (`i` followed by `ESC`).

This solution can be changed to work if you include lines that does end in white space (pasted lines from legacy code, for example):

```
autocmd InsertEnter *.[ch] :let b:insert_start = line('.')
autocmd InsertLeave *.[ch] :call <SID>StripTrailingWhitespaces()

fun! StripTrailingWhitespaces()
    let original_cursor = getpos('.')
    exe b:insert_start . ',.s/\s\+$//e'
    call setpos('.', original_cursor)
endfun
```

If the replacement on lines due to enter and exit insert mode (`i` followed by `ESC`) is a problem then the solution could save `b:changedtick-variable` when entering insert mode and check it when leaving insert mode to detect changes.

Answer (score 0):

I write a plugin named '[vim-scavenger](https://github.com/KuoE0/vim-scavenger)' to clean up multiple blank lines and trailing spaces.

Just add the following config in your .vimrc:

```
let g:scavenger_auto_clean_up_on_write = 1
```

For more detail, you can come to that [Github repo](https://github.com/KuoE0/vim-scavenger) to learn more. Feel free to give me advice to improve the plugin.

Comment: This plugin is already renamed to 'vim-janitor'. Please go [here](https://github.com/KuoE0/vim-janitor).